# OleDBAdapter not filling Dataset correctly

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am importing an excel file and filling a dataset with the contents.  Here is the first function I write:

```
Public Function ReadXLFile(ByVal FileName As String) As DataSet
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim Ds As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyAdapter As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FileName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';")
        MyAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        Ds = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyAdapter.Fill(Ds)
        Return Ds
    End Function
```

The problem I am facing is that for certain cells, the dataset does NOT put the value in, and it seems to be for certain types of highlighting in the excel sheet.  I have a line in the excel worksheet that is highlighted orange (or red in some cases).  It will not read the first column.  For example, in the excel sheet it will have

1234 Bob Jones 450  72

It will read Bob Jones and everything after it, but the first cell, 1234, it will simply not read it and in the dataset that cell is left blank.  For rows that are not highlighted, or rows where the first column is not highlighted, the data is read perfectly.

Additional Info: 
The files I am uploaded are .xls files, Microsoft Excel 97-2003.

Comment: Is first cell never read in any row? Does the first column contain values of mixed types? If that is the case, setting IMEX in connection string can be helpful. Check [Excel reading at YoursAndMyIdeas](https://yoursandmyideas.com/2011/02/05/how-to-read-or-write-excel-file-using-ace-oledb-data-provider/)

Comment: It will read some of the rows correctly.  All the rows follow the same format: 1234 Bob Jones 40 32  The first column is always filled with a 4 digit number.  The only time it doesn't read the column correctly it seems is if the highlighting is yellow or red, which is weird, because the green highlighted rows it reads fine.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!  It's weird though, because the first cell is an integer and not a mixed type. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Setting IMEX in the connection string will be helpful here. Check [Excel reading at YoursAndMyIdeas](https://yoursandmyideas.com/2011/02/05/how-to-read-or-write-excel-file-using-ace-oledb-data-provider/)
{Posting it as answer as well for proper answer tagging and the benefit of others}